# SQL Statement using Group By but need column Total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running the below SQL statement but I need total at the end.  Using SQL Server

```
SELECT tblAllocation.Allocation AS TimeSlots, COUNT(*) AS [Applicant Total] 
FROM tblAllocation  
INNER JOIN tblRegistration ON tblAllocation.AllocationID = tblRegistration.AllocationID  
INNER JOIN tblcontact ON tblRegistration.ContactID = tblcontact.ContactID
INNER JOIN tbladdress AS tbladdress_1 ON tblcontact.AddressID = tbladdress_1.AddressID  
INNER JOIN tblNadraRegistrationDates ON tblRegistration.NRegDateID = tblNadraRegistrationDates.NRegDateID  
WHERE (tblNadraRegistrationDates.[Nadra Reg Dates] = '26 April 2015')  
GROUP BY tblAllocation.Allocation;
```

Which gives the below

```
TimeSlots       Applicant Total
09:30 to 10:30  3
10:30 to 11:30  10
12:30 to 13:30  11
Reservation     8

TOTAL 32  <--- how can I get this
```

Comment: You can use `ROLLUP`.  Just add `WITH ROLLUP;` to the very end of your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `WITH ROLLUP` option for the `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN GROUPING(tblAllocation.Allocation) = 1 THEN 'Total' 
      ELSE tblAllocation.Allocation 
    END AS TimeSlots, 
    COUNT(*) AS [Applicant Total] 
FROM 
    tblAllocation  
INNER JOIN 
    tblRegistration ON tblAllocation.AllocationID = tblRegistration.AllocationID  
INNER JOIN 
    tblcontact ON tblRegistration.ContactID = tblcontact.ContactID  
INNER JOIN 
    tbladdress AS tbladdress_1 ON tblcontact.AddressID = tbladdress_1.AddressID  
INNER JOIN 
    tblNadraRegistrationDates ON tblRegistration.NRegDateID = tblNadraRegistrationDates.NRegDateID  
WHERE 
    (tblNadraRegistrationDates.[Nadra Reg Dates] = '26 April 2015')  
GROUP BY 
    tblAllocation.Allocation WITH ROLLUP;
```

You might want to use aliases for table names to shorten the query text and possibly make it more readable (but that's of course just an opinion).

[Demo SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8e2a/3)

Comment: What you do with the COALESCE can also be done more clearly using the [GROUPING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx) function: `CASE WHEN GROUPING(tblAllocation.Allocation)=1 THEN 'Total' ELSE tblAllocation.Allocation END AS TimeSlots`.

Comment: @TT. Ah yes, that's much better. I don't use rollup, grouping and grouping sets and those things too often and had forgotten about it. Thanks for the reminder. I've changed my answer to reflect this, I hope you don't mind.